# Laravel 6 : I do not understand mutators and accessors with dates

Tags: laravel

My user enters a date in this format: "d/m/Y H:i", for example "22/03/2020 11:00".

My validation is OK : `'exam_date' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y H:i',`

I have a Postgres database, the type column for the date is `timestamp(0) without time zone`.

So if I have understood, I have to transform the date before inserting it in the table . And I have to convert it after reading to display it in the good format. To do that, I have these mutator and accessor:

```
public function setExamDateAttribute($value): void
{
    $this->attributes['exam_date'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $value);
}

public function getExamDateAttribute($value)
{
    return date_format( DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $value), 'd/m/Y H:i');
}
```

I have this error:

> date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, bool given

In other words, I do not understand how mutators and accessors work with dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is nothing to do with mutator and accessor.

The problem occurs because `DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $value)`
return false;

Your column for the date is `timestamp`, so the value format is **Y-m-d H:i:s**

`DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i'` is not match to `Y-m-d H:i:s`,

You need to use `Y-m-d H:i:s` instead of `Y-m-d H:i`:

```php
public function getExamDateAttribute($value)
{
    return date_format( DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value), 'd/m/Y H:i');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot TsaiKoga. It works ! I lost 2 hours on this problem ;-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use casts for [dates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators), bools, integers and custom (in [laravel 7](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)), and you can also format the date in the model's definition:

```
protected $dates = [
    'exam_date',
];

protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i';
```

And you can format it in the blade template if needed:

```
<td>{{$exam->exam_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}</td>
```

Also your get method should be something like ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)):

```
public function getExamDateAttribute() // <-- No parameter
{
    return date_format( DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $this->exam_date), 'd/m/Y H:i'); //The value is in the model $this->exam_date
}
```

P.S: The error occurs because [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) could not create a date object and returns **FALSE**, I think this happens because the getter doesn't need a parameter and null is passed...hence the error